# Regular expression repeated sequence of characters

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

A C# learner here, 
I am trying to match a sequence of characters immediately followed by the same sequence
ex.

adad - match

1111 - match

1212 - match

12345 - no match

abcdefg - no match

So far I have came up with @"^(?=.*/*).+$" to no avail

any pointers would be great!

Comment: so the sequence is `2` chars, then look for a repeat of those `2` chars?

Comment: so in other words whats determines a 'sequence`? especially when does a sequence stop and another begin?

Comment: Thank you @JohnB, I kept reading and came to the conclusion

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can try this one**

```
(\w+)\1
```

> Explanation

- `(\w+)` - Matches any character`[A to Z, a to z, _]` one or more time.(capturing group 1).
- `\1` - Matches capturing group 1.

[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5Cw%2B%29%5C1&i=adad%0D%0A%0D%0A1111%0D%0A%0D%0A1212%0D%0A%0D%0A12345%0D%0A%0D%0Aabcdefg)